# How to get rid of Jenkins "node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by node)" message in build console

Tags: shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

Dont know whats wrong with my **Jenkins shell script console build logs** but every time I see 100's of same messages and it makes my logs very heavy to read and time consuming. I want to see just only ONE line. Is anybody gone through the same problem.? Thanks for your time.

[image]